# addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs[...] when clicking on a MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a simple component which is defined like this:

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <div>
                <Drawer open={true}>
                    <MenuItem primaryText="123" />
                </Drawer>

            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

**When I click on the MenuItem, I get these two errors, and the menu item gets a gray background.**

```
Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: react-refs-must-have-owner).  react-dom.js:17870:15
invariant http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:17870:15
[70]</ReactOwner.addComponentAsRefTo http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:10739:61
attachRef http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:11677:5
[76]</ReactRef.attachRefs http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:11696:5
attachRefs http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:11509:3
notifyAll http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:948:9
[74]</ON_DOM_READY_QUEUEING.close http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:11388:5
[100]</TransactionImpl.closeAll http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14780:11
[100]</TransactionImpl.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14727:11
[100]</TransactionImpl.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14714:13
[82]</<.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:12834:12
[82]</flushBatchedUpdates http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:12917:7
bound  self-hosted
[100]</TransactionImpl.closeAll http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14780:11
[100]</TransactionImpl.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14727:11
[51]</ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:8787:14
batchedUpdates http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:12842:10
[57]</ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:9186:7
bound  self-hosted

TypeError: component is undefined[Learn More]  bundle.js:18926:1
    ReactTransitionGroup/_this.performLeave http://192.168.0.102:8080/dist/bundle.js:18926:1
    forEach self-hosted
    componentDidUpdate http://192.168.0.102:8080/dist/bundle.js:19017:6
    bind_applyFunctionN self-hosted
    bound componentDidUpdate self-hosted
    measureLifeCyclePerf http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:4541:12
    [30]</ReactCompositeComponent._performComponentUpdate/< http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:5195:11
    notifyAll http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:948:9
    [74]</ON_DOM_READY_QUEUEING.close http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:11388:5
    [100]</TransactionImpl.closeAll http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14780:11
    [100]</TransactionImpl.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14727:11
    [100]</TransactionImpl.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14714:13
    [82]</<.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:12834:12
    [82]</flushBatchedUpdates http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:12917:7
    bound  self-hosted
    [100]</TransactionImpl.closeAll http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14780:11
    [100]</TransactionImpl.perform http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:14727:11
    [51]</ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:8787:14
    batchedUpdates http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:12842:10
    [57]</ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent http://192.168.0.102:8080/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js:9186:7
    bound
```

This is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "asd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/react-tap-event-plugin": "0.0.30",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.4",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-sticky": "^5.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "svg-url-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Does it have to do with React or with material-ui? What is the fix to the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/606 maybe this will help.

Comment: Are you calling injectTapEventPlugin() somewhere in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue.

It seems that for some reason I was including React and ReactDOM in index.html (from node_modules) but also had it in package.json as a dependency.

```
  <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

I removed the two lines above from index.html and also these lines from my webpack configuration file:

```
externals: {

"react": "React",

"react-dom": "ReactDOM"

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the fix to the problem?

One of those `react-` packages is depending *directly* on react and thus bringing their own `react` version resulting in two react versions getting loaded.

## Fix

Look for a folder `react` in `node_modules` and its sub folders to determine the package to blame.

Comment: `npm ls react` gives me `-- react@15.4.1` so I don't think there's an issue without multiple React versions...